# Upload file in two different folders and rename of file?

Tags: python, django, django-models, file-upload

I could upload two different files in the same folder using django. But I have to upload it to two different folders and before uploading file it also have to be renamed with the time it got uploaded
I have no idea as I am a beginner to django. Here is the code for uploading in same folder without renaming.

### My View.py

```
def uploadFile(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('home')
else:
    form = DocumentForm()

return render(request, 'core/upload.html', {
    'form': form
})
```

### My Model.py

```
class Document(models.Model):
document = models.FileField(upload_to="documents/")
```

### My form.py

```
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Document
    fields = ('document', )
```

> Could anyone please help me to figure out code for models.py and views.py .

Answer (score 0):

You want to rename directory or file before uploading?
Anyway you should try with django signal ***pre_save***